# How to swap a string between two running python programs?

Tags: python, string, subprocess, python-imaging-library

I want to swap an image generated by a python program to another running python program by using a string.

(I **have to use a string** because in the real application the string is coming from a C-program and not a python program but that doesn't matter)

So with one program I have to read what the other printed in the console.

But like I did it now, it don't work, the image is not correctly transmitted when I run the two programs in parallel, the image is just gray, so the reader string is not similar to the printed string.

Where is my mistake here?

**Sender Program:**

```
import time
from PIL import Image
import sys

image = Image.open("t.png")

while True:
    print(image.tobytes())
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Receiver Program:**

```
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

script_path = os.path.join('lsend.py')

p = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', script_path],
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)

while True:
    string = p.stdout.readline()
    print("image received !!!")
    print(string[0:10])
    try:
        image = Image.frombytes('RGBA',(90, 36),string,"raw")
        image.show()
    except:
        print("fail")
```

**My Image:**

[my test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSHPt.png)

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Why dont you just write it to a file ?

Comment: its too slow, in the end it should transmit realtime video as fast as possible.

Comment: `readline` is wrong, since your string is binary. You need to send the length first, then read that many bytes. Or just send a filename in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. What's the point of invoking a Python script to generate some data that a Python script reads? Why not just run that code in the original script? You kind of have to invoke this in this way `program1.py | program2.py` Wouldn't you be better off using a socket - then either program could be entirely independent and running on a different machine even. Why are you approaching this that way? I think you are trying to solve a different problem that you haven't told us about - or don't realise you have :-)

Comment: Yes its a bit different, because I have a wireless lora model connected to a raspberry pi and a c program which can print out the text the wireless model is receiving.        So the image is printed as a string into the console by the C-program and I want to read this string with a python program to get the image back. So that I can transmit photos or maybe a video live stream with low fps by a sender python program, which is turning the image into a string, giving it to another C-program to send it, and then receive it with another raspberry pi and show the photos with a python program.

Comment: LIKE THIS: image -> sender.py -(str)> sender.c -> wireless ))) receiver.c -(str)> receiver.py -> image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues with your code:

- there is no message boundary - the sender just sends a continuous stream of bytes and the receiver has no idea where one image ends and the next begins, and
- `Image.tobytes()` seems to want to pair up with `Image.frombuffer()` rather than `Image.frombytes()` - no idea why!

So, I made your sender just send a single image and your receiver just receive a single image. I guess you would want to put some protocol on top that says how many bytes are coming, then the receiver would stop after receiving one image and start expecting a new byte count.

Here's `lsend.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('lora.png').convert('RGB')
sys.stdout.buffer.write(image.tobytes())
```

And here is `receiver.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from PIL import Image
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, DEVNULL

process = Popen(['./lsend.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL)
stdout, _ = process.communicate()

try:
   image = Image.frombuffer('RGB',(90,36),stdout)
   image.show()
except:
   print("fail")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the end result is to transmit video, I would recommend using sockets.

Python should provide everything you need in the `socket` library

This should give a general idea of how sending data over a socket works:

#### sender.py

```
import socket

# Host the socket on localhost for this example.
# This could send over a network too though.
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8000

# Initialize the socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))

# The number of connections to listen for.
sock.listen(5)
print("Server listening.")

while True:

    try:
        # Accept an incoming connection from the client.
        client, addr = sock.accept()
        print("Accepted connection from client.")

        # Wait until the client sends data.
        data = client.recv(1024)
        print(data)

        # Send some data back to the client.
        s = "Hello client"
        client.send(s.encode())

        client.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Connecting to the socket is similar to hosting it. Instead of calling `socket.bind`, just call the `socket.connect`, and remove the `socket.listen`.

#### receiver.py

```
import socket

# The host and port the socket is hosted on.
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8000

# Create the socket and connect to the server.
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, port))

# Send the server some data.
s = "Hello server"
sock.send(s.encode())

# And receive some back.
data = sock.recv(1024)
print(data)
```